# Map and reverse sublists scheme

Tags: dictionary, scheme, reverse

I wanted to write a function that reverses all the sub-lists in a list (but only the sublists of the top level). I tried to figure out if I could just `filter` the list and do the `reverse` before using `map` by doing
`(filter list? (reverse '((1 2) 9 (16 5) 64)))`, but that just reverses to `((16 5) (1 2))`. 
I am looking for an output like: `((2 1) 9 (5 16) 64))`.

I am supposed to use `map` and `reverse`, but I just couldn't get there to start with.

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, you just need to ask if each item is a list before trying to reverse it:

```
(define lst '((1 2) 9 (16 5) 64))

(map (lambda (e)
       (if (list? e) (reverse e) e))
     lst)

> '((2 1) 9 (5 16) 64)
```

`filter` won't work in this case, as you're interested in processing *all* the elements in the input list, even though only the actual lists need to be reversed.

Comment: @AdeqHero you're welcome! if this answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it as correct, by clicking on the check mark on its left